# Google Maps Api Key give Grey Tiles

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, keystore

I used the debug key and my application worked just fine but when i generated my own api key my google maps is only diplaying grey tiles.  Here is my xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/bg" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="400px"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
    android:apiKey="0FngR799edZTGCRHpFXeNAlq6bB8LjrNCFAyPPg"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true" />
```

I did everything right to get my api key I have even tried it twice with two different keystores and copied and pasted MD5 fingerprint... Here is my manifest

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="unjustentertainment.mything.com"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >


    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MyThingsActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Items" 
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
                   <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="unjustentertainment.mything.com.CLEARSCREEN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

      </activity>

        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
                    android:name=".Data" 
                  android:label="@string/app_name"

                  />

          <activity
       android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
          />


                <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
</application>



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

I just can't figure out why non of my api keys are working. Any ideas are helpful. Thanks I have also already signed my package

Comment: Did you sign it with your development key and then tryed running it? If that doesn't work try to get the key again, sometimes it get changed (think if it gets called too many times from wrong source).

Answer (score 1):

You have to sign the app with your keystore while using your own API key, not with the debug keystore.

If you haven't gone through this process, the easiest way is through *Eclipse* (with GUI)

- Right mouse button click on the Project.
- Go to Android Tools.
- Export Signed Application.

Comment: Yea I already did that That is how i got my keystore in the first place

Answer (score 1):

Try to put

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.EMBED"/>
```

inside the  of the map activity.

If this doesn't work, try to remove the backgroud...

Answer (score 1):

- If you sign with the debug key --> use debug apiKey for maps.
- If you sign with your own key --> generate your own apiKey.

[That should be all; you can generate the API key here.](http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html)

[Go to this link for more info regarding the same.](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html)

Do not paste the `MD5 value` of your key into the `apiKey = attribute` of your layout.

Comment: I signed with my own key so I posted my own key into my layout apiKey= value but I am testing that out with my device which is in debug mode should it still work?

Comment: Yes it doesn't matter on which device you run, you can even send the release-signed APK to the emulator and test it there.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone who got stuck, I had this issue with an older app at work. I tried generating a maps-api level 2 and api level 3 key without any luck (tried all of the tips here).

When I switched to an API level 1 key, I was able to get it to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The API Key for `debug` ONLY works on emulators.

If you use Eclipse to load the software in `debug mode` to a handset, you will get tiles, not a map.

- If you update the mapview with a `release` API key, then use Eclipse
  `EXPORT` to create an apk file.
- Copy this to the SD card on the handset.
- Then use an installer app (download free from Google Play) to install
  it on the phone IT WORKS!!!